# AWS Athena query to find Date column has String or not satisfying timestamp format

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I was testing Sprak 3 upgrades in AWS Athena and need to check date columns whether timestamp format is proper or not,Can any one please give me query to check whether date columns has any Values other than Timestamp format

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a `varchar` column you can try using [`date_parse`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_parse) wrapped in [`try`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#id4):

```sql
select *
from table 
where try(date_parse(string_column, 'your_expected_format')) is null -- assuming no original nulls in column
```

Or via `try_cast` for "standard" format:

```sql
select *
from table 
where try_cast(string_column as timestamp) -- assuming no original nulls in column
```